# UIStackView - Distribute views evenly from the centre

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios9, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView`,inside a `UIScrollView` to show dynamically added subviews horizontally arranged. Current solution will start displaying items from the left, I would like to start distributing items from the centre without changing the width and height of the subviews. How do I do that?  Im also open to solutions which doesn't use `UIStackView` as well. That way I could support devices < iOS9.

[image: Curent]

(**Current**)

[image: Expected]

(**Expected**)

Comment: Are you working in Swift or Objective C?

Comment: Im working on Swift 2.0

Comment: Are you going to cap the amount of subViews at 3 inside the stackView?

Comment: Subviews inside the UIStackView would come dynamic, could be n numbers. That's why I need the UIScrollView here.

Comment: I have 4 buttons, all 50 x 50. I set the Stack View to `Equal Spacing` and constrained the height and width of the buttons. The first and last button were on the edge of the stack view. To add equal spacing to the start and end of the stack view, I just added two 1x50 labels as the first and last elements in the stack view. Hacky, but works ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Short answer :**

ScrollView constraints

```
Leading >= 0, Trailing >= 0, Top >= 0, Bottom >= 0
Center X  and Center Y
```

StackView constraints

```
Leading = 0, Trailing = 0, Top = 0, Bottom = 0
StackView width = ScrollView width (priority low :250)
StackView height = ScrollView height
```

**Long answer**

Firstly, your structure is good, we have :

```
UIScrollView
     UIStackView (horizontal)
         Subviews
```

So, to reach the goal we should :

- Center the `UIScrollView`
- Set the contentSize of the `UIScrollView` equal to the intrinsic content
  size of the `UIStackView`

Here is how to do it :

**Step 1: Center the frame of the UIScrollView**

[image]

`CenterY` and `CenterX` constraints used to center the frame of the `UIScrollView`

`Leading Space` >= 0, `Trailling Space` >= 0, `Top Space` >= 0, `Bottom Spac`e >= 0 are used to prevent the frame of the UIScrollView to exceed the frame of the parent view

I used placeholder intrinsic size to don't show errors related to the contentSize of the `UIScrollView`  (because we don't have yet the subviews so the contentSize).

Now, the frame of our `UIScrollView` is Ok, go to the next step :)

**Step 2: add the horizontal UIStackView**

[image]

- Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing constraints are used to fix
  UIStackView frame
- Equal Height and equal width used to calculate the
  contentSize of the UIScrollView

PS. Any change in the frame of the UIStackView, change the contentSize of the UIScrollView

**Step 3: add subviews**

Because we use `Fill Distribution` in the `UIStackView` all `subviews` must have a intrinsic content size (or height and width constraints (not preferred)).
For example, if we use `Fill Equally`, only one `subview` with intrinsic content size (or height and width constraints (not preferred)) sufficient, the other subviews size will be equal to this one.

For Example: I will add 3 labels (please remove the placeholder intrinsic size of the `UIScrollView`)

[image]

It works !! no, no, not yet try to add fourth and five labels :)

**Why ?**

To understand we will calculate the frame of each element of the view with two examples :

The parent view size : 200, 200 
The first label intrinsic content size : 120, 50 
the second label  intrinsic content size : 150, 50

**First example (only the first label in the `UIStackView`)**

- `UIStackView` intrinsic content size = 120, 50
- `UIScrollView` contentSize = 120, 50
- `UIScrollView` frame = 40, 75, 120, 50

*All frames are OK*

**Second example (with the two labels)**

- `UIScrollView` frame = 0, 0, 200, 50
- `UIScrollView` contentSize = 200, 50
- `UIStackView` intrinsic content size = 200, 50

So, the `UIStackView` can't show correctly the two labels (because the width of `UIStackView` lower than the two labels width), and we don't have the scroll because, the `UIStackView` constraint width is equal to UIScrollView width's.
It works when the `UIStackView` intrinsic content size is lower than the max `UIScrollView` frame.

To Fix that, we change the priority of the width constraint to a value lower than the `UIStackView` intrinsic content size priority value, and all works fine :)

[image]

Hope that helps.

[Code source](https://github.com/HamzaGhazouani/Stackoverflow/tree/master/ScrollView%2BStackView)