# UIStackView inside UIScrollView position

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ScrollView that starts at a Y position of 50, inside the ScrollView I have a StackView with dynamic elements added. The elements are added and the scroll works as expected. However the StackView is drawn at Y=0 so that the first element is against 0,0 of the application while the ScrollView is at 0,50.

I have tried several things from assigning constraints, to changing the frame.origin.y position and frame.offsetInPlace.

Are there any recommendations out there? It all is being done dynamically with SWIFT and without a xib.

Comment: you can find here an example of the scrollView with the stackView : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35438836/2477632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of scrollView with stackView here:

[UIStackView - Distribute views evenly from the centre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432204/uistackview-distribute-views-evenly-from-the-centre/35438836#35438836)

Thanks Hamza Ghazouani for the tip.