# UIStackView inside scrollView

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to put a UIStackView inside a scrollView.

Within this I want the following:

- Top view is also a UIStackView that contains 2 labels.
- Second view is a custom view that will remain same size.
- Third view is a UIView that I want to use to add other customUIViews to. So in code I will be doing addSubview and this view will need to change size depending on the size of the subview added to it.
- Fourth View is 2 labels in stackView.

I have tried setting it up with the following: (Plus the third view's hugging priority is higher as I want it to grow and shrink depending on size of view added.)

[image]

However I am getting the following result:

[image]

Has anyone had any luck adding a UIStackView to a scroll view and within that stackView having a view that resize depending on the content?

The other option is maybe using a tableView. Though would prefer to use a stack view.

Comment: if you don't mind add the design screen.let me check the UIDesign..

Comment: Hey, you can find here an example of the scrollView with the stackView : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438836/2477632, hope that helps